# Ordered One-to-Many List with Sequence Number column in Join Table with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I have the following entities

```
class ItemList {
  long id;
  List<Item> items;
}
```

and

```
class Item {
  long id;
  String name;
}
```

I would like to represent them with the following tables

```
table ITEM_LIST (
  item_list_id number primary key
);

table ITEM (
  item_id number primary key,
  name varchar(255) not null
);
```

for the primary entities, and a join table for the relationship;

```
table ITEM_LIST_REL (
  item_list_id number,
  item_id number,
  seq_no number
);
```

where `seq_no` gives the sequence number of the item in the item list - in effect, the index of the item in the `List` object.

How can I map that using Hibernate or java.persistence annotations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041189/jpa-many-to-many-with-extra-column